# Java/C++ TCP socket receive issue

Tags: java, c++, sockets

I have the following scenario:

A Java program invokes a C++ program to capture and return network packets. The C++ program has special permissions set on it to allow for network packet capture. The two programs communicate via a TCP socket. The Java program sends a simple text command to tell the C++ program what it wants. The C++ program captures packets and sends them back on the socket.

The socket is being established successfully and initial information is making it across. When the C++ program connects the socket, it sends a simple "ready" to let the Java program know it's connected and ready to go. The Java program then sends its first command to collect some packets. These text messages are successfully sent and received.

The C++ program captures the packets and sends them on the socket (collections of bytes). I have verified this by seeing the traffic in Wireshark. However, the Java program does not appear to receive any of this data until I kill the C++ program with Control-C. At that point, the Java program prints out the data it has received (although it does not seem to have received everything that was sent).

I don't understand what seems to be holding up the flow of information. What am I missing?

UPDATE:

As requested, I am including below the C++ and Java code.

C++: [Suggested focus on the `openSocket`, `send` and `capture` functions]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <cerrno>

#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#include "PacketCapture.h"

#define SNAP_SIZE 8192
#define COMMS_BUF_SIZE 256

struct capture_data
{
  int length;
  u_char* buffer;
};

bool openSocket(const std::string address, const int port);
void cleanUp(void);

int send(void *buffer, int length);
void capture(const int count, const std::string filter);

void split(char *value, const char *delimSet, std::vector<std::string> &list);

std::string printCaptureStatus(const int status);
void printPayload(const u_char *payload, int length);
void printHexASCIILine(const u_char *payload, int length, int offset);

int g_sock;
PacketCapture *g_pcap;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  if (argc != 5) {
    std::cerr << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " <address> <port> <device> <timeout>"
        << std::endl;
    std::exit(1);
  }

  std::string address = argv[1];
  int port = atoi(argv[2]);
  std::string device = argv[3];
  int timeout = atoi(argv[4]);

  std::cout << "address: " << address << std::endl;
  std::cout << "port: " << port << std::endl;
  std::cout << "device: " << device << std::endl;
  std::cout << "timeout: " << timeout << std::endl;

  g_pcap = new PacketCapture(device, SNAP_SIZE, timeout);

  if (g_pcap == NULL) {
    std::cerr << "Could not create packet capture" << std::endl;
    std::exit(1);
  }

  if (!openSocket(address, port)) {
    std::cerr << "Could not create socket" << std::endl;
    std::exit(1);
  }

  char buffer[COMMS_BUF_SIZE];
  std::vector < std::string > tokens;

  while (true) {
    memset(buffer, 0, COMMS_BUF_SIZE);
    int received = recv(g_sock, buffer, COMMS_BUF_SIZE, 0);

    if (received > 0) {
      std::cout << "received: " << buffer << std::endl;
      tokens.clear();
      split(buffer, "#\n", tokens);

      std::cout << tokens.size() << " tokens" << std::endl;
      for (std::vector<std::string>::iterator it = tokens.begin();
          it != tokens.end(); ++it) {
        std::cout << "'" << *it << "'" << std::endl;
      }

      if (tokens[0].compare("STOP") == 0) {
        std::cout << "stopping" << std::endl;
        break;
      }

      if (tokens[0].compare("CAPTURE") == 0) {
        int count = atoi(tokens[1].c_str());
        std::string filter = tokens[2];
        std::cout << "capture: count: " << count << ", filter: " << filter
            << std::endl;
        capture(count, filter);
      }
    } else {
      // TODO error condition
    }

    usleep(1000);
  }

  cleanUp();
  exit(0);
}

void cleanUp(void)
{
  g_pcap->close();
  delete g_pcap;
  close(g_sock);
}

bool openSocket(const std::string address, const int port)
{
  g_sock = 0;
  struct sockaddr_in server_addr;

  if ((g_sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) {
    std::cerr << "Socket creation error" << std::endl;
    return false;
  }

  memset(&server_addr, 0, sizeof(server_addr));
  server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  server_addr.sin_port = htons(port);

  // Convert IPv4 and IPv6 addresses from text to binary form.
  if (inet_pton(AF_INET, address.c_str(), &server_addr.sin_addr) <= 0) {
    std::cerr << "Invalid address/ Address not supported" << std::endl;
    return false;
  }

  if (connect(g_sock, (struct sockaddr *) &server_addr, sizeof(server_addr))
      < 0) {
    std::cerr << "Connection Failed" << std::endl;
    return false;
  }

  char* ready = "READY";
  send(ready, strlen(ready));

  return true;
}

int send(void *buffer, int length)
{
  int result = send(g_sock, buffer, length, 0);

  if (result < 0) {
    std::cerr << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
  }

  return result;
}

void capture(const int count, const std::string filter)
{
  std::vector<struct capture_data> captureList;
  g_pcap->setFilter(filter);

  u_char data[SNAP_SIZE];
  int length = 0;
  int status = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    status = g_pcap->capturePacketData(data, &length);

    std::cout << "capture: " << (i + 1) << ", status: "
        << printCaptureStatus(status) << ", length: " << length << std::endl;
    printPayload(data, length);

    if (status == 1 && length > 0) {
      struct capture_data capture;
      capture.length = length;
      capture.buffer = data;
      captureList.push_back(capture);
    }
  }

  std::cout << "capture count: " << captureList.size() << std::endl;

  // Send number of captures.
  int size = captureList.size();
  send(&size, sizeof(int));

  for (int i = 0; i < captureList.size(); i++) {
    struct capture_data capture = captureList[i];
    std::cout << "sending" << std::endl;
    // Send the capture data length.
    send(&(capture.length), sizeof(int));
    // Send capture data.
    int numSent = send(capture.buffer, capture.length);
    std::cout << "sent: " << numSent << std::endl;
  }
}

std::string printCaptureStatus(const int status)
{
  switch (status) {
    case 0:
      return "TIMEOUT";
    case 1:
      return "OK";
    case -1:
      return "ERROR";
    case -2:
      return "EOD";
    default:
      return "UNKNOWN";
  }
}

void split(char *value, const char *delimSet, std::vector<std::string> &list)
{
  char *ptr = strtok(value, delimSet);

  while (ptr != NULL) {
    list.push_back(ptr);
    ptr = strtok(NULL, delimSet);
  }
}

void printPayload(const u_char *payload, int length)
{
  int len_rem = length;
  int line_width = 16; /* number of bytes per line */
  int line_len;
  int offset = 0; /* zero-based offset counter */
  const u_char *ch = payload;

  if (length <= 0) {
    return;
  }

  /* data fits on one line */
  if (length <= line_width) {
    printHexASCIILine(ch, length, offset);
    return;
  }

  /* data spans multiple lines */
  while (true) {
    /* compute current line length */
    line_len = line_width % len_rem;
    /* print line */
    printHexASCIILine(ch, line_len, offset);
    /* compute total remaining */
    len_rem = len_rem - line_len;
    /* shift pointer to remaining bytes to print */
    ch = ch + line_len;
    /* add offset */
    offset = offset + line_width;

    /* check if we have line width chars or less */
    if (len_rem <= line_width) {
      /* print last line and get out */
      printHexASCIILine(ch, len_rem, offset);
      break;
    }
  }

  return;
}

void printHexASCIILine(const u_char *payload, int length, int offset)
{
  int i;
  int gap;
  const u_char *ch;

  /* offset */
  printf("%06x   ", offset);

  /* hex */
  ch = payload;

  for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    printf("%02x ", *ch);
    ch++;

    /* print extra space after 8th byte for visual aid */
    if (i == 7) {
      printf(" ");
    }
  }

  /* print space to handle line less than 8 bytes */
  if (length < 8) {
    printf(" ");
  }

  /* fill hex gap with spaces if not full line */
  if (length < 16) {
    gap = 16 - length;

    for (i = 0; i < gap; i++) {
      printf("   ");
    }
  }

  printf("   ");

  /* ASCII (if printable) */
  ch = payload;

  for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    if (isprint(*ch)) {
      printf("%c", *ch);
    } else {
      printf(".");
    }

    ch++;
  }

  printf("\n");
  return;
}
```

Java:

```
package xyz;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

import xyz.HexDump;

public class TestCapture {

  private static final int    PORT = 9000;

  private static ServerSocket serverSocket;
  private static Socket       clientSocket;
  // private static BufferedReader input;
  private static InputStream  input;
  private static PrintWriter  output;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    initSocket();
    process();
    close();
  }

  private static void initSocket() {
    try {
      System.out.println("waiting for connection");
      serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
      clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();

      // input = new BufferedReader(new
      // InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
      input = clientSocket.getInputStream();
      output = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);

      // should be "READY"
      byte[] data = new byte[8192];
      receiveData(data);
      String response = new String(data);
      System.out.println(response);

      System.out.println("accepted connection");
      System.out.println("port: " + clientSocket.getPort() + ", local port: " + clientSocket.getLocalPort());
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  private static void process() {
    try {
      // byte[] data = new byte[8192];

      // for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      output.println("CAPTURE#20#tcp port 61616");

      // int numBytes = receiveData(data);
      // System.out.println("received: " + numBytes);
      // System.out.println(HexDump.dump(data, numBytes, 16, true));

      List<CaptureInfo> captures = receiveData();

      System.out.println("captures: " + captures.size());

      for (int i = 0; i < captures.size(); i++) {
        CaptureInfo info = captures.get(i);
        System.out.println("capture: " + (i + 1) + ", length: " + info.length);
        System.out.println(HexDump.dump(info.data, info.length, 16, true));
      }
      // }

      output.println("STOP");
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  private static int receiveData(byte[] data) {
    int numBytes = 0;

    try {
      numBytes = input.read(data);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return numBytes;
  }

  private static List<CaptureInfo> receiveData() {
    List<CaptureInfo> result = new LinkedList<CaptureInfo>();
    byte[] data = new byte[8192];
    int numBytes = 0;

    while (numBytes != -1) {
      try {
        numBytes = input.read(data);
      } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }

      if (numBytes >= 0) {
        result.add(new CaptureInfo(numBytes, data));
      } else {
        System.out.println("EOD");
      }
    }

    return result;
  }

  private static void close() {
    try {
      clientSocket.close();
      serverSocket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  private static class CaptureInfo {
    int    length;
    byte[] data;

    CaptureInfo(int length, byte[] data) {
      this.length = length;
      this.data = data;
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: I have a few guesses, but no answers without code. Maybe post the C++ code that writes to the socket, and the Java code that reads from the socket? Should be a good place to start.

Comment: Your java program only prints the data after C++ program finishes sending the data, from the logic in function List<CaptureInfo> receiveData(), the while loop